# mathscript glyphs in nomenclature list

Tags: amsmath, nomenclature

I am trying to use a glyph defined by \mathscr{F} in a list of nomenclature. The explanation shows in the list fine, but the glyph doesn't. Anyone come across this before or have a solution\workaround?
Probably not strictly a minimum example below, but I thought it may be an upshot of my code perhaps.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
     \makenomenclature
     \renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature \& Abbreviations}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{
    \protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
        \twocolumn

        \phantomsection {chapter}{Nomenclature \& Abbreviations}
                \chaptermark{Nomenclature \& Abbreviations}
                \printnomenclature[1.8cm]
                \pagebreak
$\mathscr{f}=h \nu$
\nomenclature{\mathscr{f}}{Frequency}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you edit your MWE so that it (a) actually compiles and (b) is minimal?  `mathsrsfs` should be `mathrsfs` and you appear to have forgotten `hyperref` but it's not obvious why you need it here.

Comment: You have `\mathscr{f}` which should be `\mathscr{F}`; there's no lowercase character in the RSFS font.

Comment: Apologies for the error in this I've corrected it

Answer (score 2):

1. The package name is `mathrsfs`, not `mathsrsfs`
2. If you want a script ‘F’, you have to type `\mathscr{F}`, not `\mathscr{f}`
3. In the argument to `\nomenclature` it's necessary to provide the math mode shift commands: `\nomenclature{$\mathscr{F}$}{Frequency}`
4. If you redefine `\nomname` you don't need to provide `\chapter` explicitly, nor `\chaptermark`.
5. `\phantomsection{chapter}{...}` is wrong.

Complete example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature \& Abbreviations}

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature[1.8cm]

\pagebreak

$\mathscr{F}=h\nu$
\nomenclature[Fscr]{$\mathscr{F}$}{Frequency}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah That is fantastic. Thank you so much Enrico!